# Create Table from an already joined table

Tags: sql

I dont know if this question fit in here.

So i already have a table X created with values from table Y.
Now i have to get just the values from Table X and left join some more values from table Y and create the table Z.

```
Table X 
ID   Car   Color
1     BMW   Red
1     Ford   Blue
2     VW     Black

Table Y
ID  Car  Color Height Weight
1   BMW   Red   2      1000
1   Ford  Blue  4      1500
1   Tesla Green 3       850
1....
```

I tried it with a inner join on the ID, but now i get all the ID´s from Table Y and not just the ID´s from table X.

```
ID  CAR  Color Height  Weight
   1   BMW   Red   2      1000
   1   Ford  Blue  4      1500
   1   Tesla Green 3       850
```

But i need to get this:

```
ID  Car  Color Height Weight
1   BMW   Red   2      1000
1   Ford  Blue  4      1500
```

I know i could use Table X and left join the values, but is there a "cleaner", faster way? I thought it could be done with a inner join, but it doesnt work.
Or do i have to inner join on the ID, on the Car, on the Color?
I hope the question is understandable.

```
create table tableZ AS 
select tx.ID, ty.CAR,ty.Height,ty.Weight
from .... ty 
INNER JOIN ... tx on (tx.ID = ty.ID)
```

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ID` is a very bad name for a column that isn't the table's unique ID. Anyway, you obviously want to join on ID, car and color, so do so:

```
create table tableZ AS 
select tx.ID, ty.CAR, ty.Height, ty.Weight
from ty 
INNER JOIN tx on tx.ID = ty.ID and tx.car = ty.car and tx.color = ty.color;
```

(If you join on `id` alone, you combine every tx row with every ty row of the same `id`.)

Comment: Now i can´t left join on the created table, the key is the ID. Just wanted to LEFT JOIN XXX.XXX t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID.  Do i need to LEFT JOIN it another way, on the other table...which i already tryed and it doenst work too.

Comment: Change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and you have an outer join. (`INNER` and `OUTER` are optional keywords, though; you can omit them, if you like.) This would return a row for VW/Black which doesn't have a match in ty and is therefore not in the results of a mere inner join.